# How to use tri2grid matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a problem with tri2grid. I have a set of coordinate points on a triangle and the value of interest at those points (3 vectors). I would like to create a grid using tri2grid command inside my triangle and see my solution (a matrix) on the grid points. I did the following but I got in my solution matrix (fGrid) NaN values. I read that NaN values occur when your grid points are outside the original mesh but I create the grid on the same triangle of the mesh, do not really understand why I got those NaN values.Anyone can help??

```
Xt=[zgauss(:,1)];
Yt=[zgauss(:,2)];
tri = delaunay(Xt,Yt);

xGrids = linspace(min(Xt),max(Xt),100);
yGrids = linspace(min(Yt),max(Yt),100);

[Xgrid,Ygrid]=meshgrid(xGrids,yGrids);

fGrid = tri2grid([Xt,Yt]',tri',f_on_gauss,Xgrid,Ygrid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have NaN values because a rectangular grid defined over the maximum x and y range of a triangle will contain points outside the triangle.  Draw a triangle on a piece of paper, then try drawing a rectangle which completely covers the triangle, and you'll see the issue quickly.

To see where your actual grid lies you can just plot it out:

```
plot(Xt,Yt,'g.'); % your triangle points
hold on
plot(Xgrid,YGrid, 'r.'); % your mesh points
```

The NaN values are not necessarily an issue, depending on what you're planning to do with the output.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, now I see, buuttt NaN values are an issue for me because I will do a contour plot with the result and can not use contour with those NaN values.

Comment: Any idea how to avoid this behaviour??

Comment: I would think that `contour` simply ignores `NaN` data, but if not, why not just change it to something else, like zeros?